# My repaint function is not calling my paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I have read multiple topics about why repaint does not call the paintComponent, yet I have not been able to combine those answers with my code to get it working. I have to do an assignment for school where in a GUI I give the X and Y coordinate for N trucks to be drawn, first one on X and Y and the rest randomly.

```
public class TruckMaker extends JPanel {
    public int y1;
    public int x1;
    public static Double circle, circle2, circle3;
    public static java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double rectangle, rectangle2;
    Random random = new Random();

    public TruckMaker() {
        circle = new Ellipse2D.Double();
        circle2 = new Ellipse2D.Double();
        circle3 = new Ellipse2D.Double();
        rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double();
        rectangle2 = new Rectangle2D.Double();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fill(circle);
        g2.fill(rectangle);
        g2.fill(rectangle2);
        g2.fill(circle2);
        g2.fill(circle3);
        System.out.println("Paint component is being called");
    }

    public void getTrucks(int x, int y, int n) {
        boolean firstTimer = true;
        while (n > 0) {
            if (firstTimer) {
                x1 = x;
                y1 = y;
                rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, 50, 50);
                circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x1 + 25, (y1 + 65), 25, 25);
                rectangle2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1 + 65, y1 - 25, 150, 75);
                circle2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x1 + 140, (y1 + 65), 25, 25);
                circle3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x1 + 175, (y1 + 65), 25, 25);
                n--;
                firstTimer = false;
            } else {
                x1 = (random.nextInt(750) + 1);
                y1 = y;
                rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1, y1, 50, 50);
                circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(x1 + 25, (y1 + 65), 25, 25);
                rectangle2 = new Rectangle2D.Double(x1 + 65, y1 - 25, 150, 75);
                circle2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x1 + 140, (y1 + 65), 25, 25);
                circle3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(x1 + 175, (y1 + 65), 25, 25);
                n--;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

and here is where I call the `TruckMaker`

```
public class TruckMain {

    private TruckMaker truck;
    private TruckMain truckmain;
    private final static int FRAME_WIDTH = 750;
    private final static int FRAME_HEIGHT  = 750;
    public final static JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    private final static BorderLayout border = new BorderLayout();
    public final static JLabel x = new JLabel("x: ");

    public final static JLabel y = new JLabel("y: ");

    public final static JLabel n = new JLabel("n: ");
    private static JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();

    private static JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(5);
    private static JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(5);
    private static JTextField textField3 = new JTextField(5);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TruckMaker truck = new TruckMaker();
        TruckMain truckMain = new TruckMain();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.add(truck);
        frame.setLayout(border);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        controlPanel.add(x);
        controlPanel.add(textField1);
        controlPanel.add(y);
        controlPanel.add(textField2);
        controlPanel.add(n);
        controlPanel.add(textField3);
        controlPanel.add(startButton);
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                int x1 = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
                int y1 = Integer.parseInt(textField2.getText());
                int n1 = Integer.parseInt(textField3.getText());
                truck.getTrucks(x1,y1,n1);
                }
                });
        frame.add(controlPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where `repaint` is even defined.

Comment: The problem is that your `TruckMaker` component is not visible on the frame, so when `repaint` is called, there's nothing to repaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `repaint` method seems to work fine; the problem is in your `main` method and how you construct your frame. It seems like your `TruckMaker` component is not visible at all, so `repaint` has nothing to do. Maybe this is just a mistake in your posted code, since I can not even see your controls panel, but instead of adding the components directly to `frame`, you have to add them to the frame's `contentPane`:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(truck, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.getContentPane().add(controlPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

After this fix, both the control panel and the `TruckMaker` component are visible and the `paintComponent` method is being called.

---

There's also an (unrelated) issue with the types of `circle`, `circle2`, etc. I guess this should be

```
public static Ellipse2D.Double circle, circle2, circle3;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem. Finding the solution to a GUI problem is a lot harder in comparison to "logic" errors haha.